# Suspicious data usage by apps

Tags: privacy, miui, fingerprint

Here are a list of apps that I found on my phone:[image: com.huaqin.factory][image: dialogger][image: silead][image: silead-manager]

Now all of these apps seem to be preinstalled as they aren't device administrators and are impossible to disable or uninstall.

They all seem to be sending data somewhere on a daily basis, as seen here:
[image: usage]

Now obviously a smartphone would require a fingerprint service as well as one for factory tests, but why should they send data continuously? What is the data that they send? Is there any way to restrict it?
Device is a POCO M3 running MIUI.

Comment: [https://www.xda-developers.com/report-android-phones-transmit-data-to-adups-a-chinese-firm](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815194535/https://www.xda-developers.com/report-android-phones-transmit-data-to-adups-a-chinese-firm)

Comment: I have Poco M3 but I have only com.huaqin.

Comment: @alecxs The part that worries is the most is that I can't find any information online. My phone has been acting weird as well so maybe I'll have to replace it.